# Want to rename mp3 files from 1 to words mentioned in column1 in that order

Tags: excel, vba

Rename the mp3 file, using words in column in a worksheet:

```
Sub rename
 Dim i as integer
 Dim new_name As String
     i=1
    Do While Range("A1").Offset(i,0)<>""
    Range("A1").Offset(i-1,0).Select
    new_name=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Offset(i-1, 0)

    Name "G:\" &i& ".mp3" as"G:\" & new_name & ".mp3"
     i = i+1
    Loop
 End Sub
```

At the line `Name "G:\" ...` the line is highlighted in yellow.. and says error 53!

Comment: What error do you get and where?

Answer (score 0):

you can't simply declare the old name as the new name. You actually need a file system object to rename the files. I used the [moveFile method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2wcf3ba6(v=vs.84).aspx) this will rename the file.

the `as` keyword is used when declaring a variable. you `Dim` a `variable_name` `as` a specific `data_type` for instance `dim idx as integer`

first add these things to your declarations

```
Dim fso
Dim SrcFile As String
Dim DestFile As String
```

then you replace this line

```
'Name "G:\" &i& ".mp3" as"G:\" & new_name & ".mp3"
```

with all of this

```
SrcFile = "G:\" & i & ".mp3"
DestFile = "G:\" & new_name & ".mp3"
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If Not fso.FileExists(SrcFile) Then
    MsgBox SrcFile & " does not exist!", vbExclamation, "Source File Missing"

ElseIf Not fso.FileExists(DestFile) Then
    Call fso.MoveFile(SrcFile, DestFile)

Else
    MsgBox DestFile & file & " already exists!", vbExclamation, "Destination File Exists"

End If

Set fso = Nothing
```